# Compare time with date in express

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to compare two dates with time and i want if time difference more than one minute then expire message should display otherwise verify message should display.How can i do this here is my code

```
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var day=dateFormat(new Date(date), "yyyy-mm-dd h:MM:ss");  //2018-08-01 11:02:27
var currenttime=dateFormat(new Date(), "yyyy-mm-dd h:MM:ss"); //2018-08-01 11:08:48

var compare = day - currenttime;
console.log(compare);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a JavaScript Date object you can use [`Date.valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) to get the milliseconds from the epoch of that time and then do plain subtraction to get the difference. If it is greater than 60000 then expire.

```
// I swapped your values on either side of the subtraction operator 
// to prevent a negative time difference
var compare = currentTime.valueOf() - day.valueOf()
var isExpired = compare >= 60000

console.log('isExpired', isExpired)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare after generating timestamp of both time. Few ways to generate timestamp

1) +new Date()

2) https://momentjs.com/

Example using moment js :

```
var compare =  moment().format('X') - moment("1995-12-25").format('X'); // In seconds
```